# Procedural Snow with Particles

Tags: particles, external-applications

Basically, I want to have a quick way of simulating snow. My plan was to use particles to simulate where snow would fall, but I can't figure out a workflow. The only tutorial/article that I could find was one for *3DSMax*. *How can I do the same in Blender?* The *3DSMax* tutorial is 100% what i was looking for, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in Blender.

[Link](http://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/procedural-snow-in-3d-studio-max--cg-8776) to tutorial.

Hope you guys can point me to any plugins or ways of achieving that tutorial's results.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching i did end up finding a plugin for Blender that does what i need! Its called Cubesurfer - its by Jean-Francois Gallant.

So what you do is spawn particals and the add on spawns mesh around those particals, if the balls of mesh touch it becomes one solid block. Then you need to smooth it all out with a smooth modifier. Done!

Comment: Could you include a link to this solution?

Answer (score 2):

I've only a week ago done a basic but effective looking snowfall. I'll try and place the Blender file up here.  I used two emitters, one for distant flakes and another for closer and a circular variety.  The Blender file  (just over 3 MB)...

[image]

As for directional flow, go to the emitter's "Velocity" tab and drag X, Y or Z values to suit.  You can also turn gravity off if desired.  You'll find that under the "Field Weights" tab further down.

As snowflakes can flutter on the way down, I've adjusted the Brownian value in the "Physics" tab.

Apologise for the missing texture files - tried to pack them into the Blender file but it kept coming up with "cannot find errors" even when I moved the files into the project's folder and re-saved.

Everything you need is still there and the snow still works though. (CTL-A)

Screenshot -

[image]

Comment: You can upload the .blend to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and edit you answer to include the link given to you once the upload is complete. But there's a size limit, 30MB I think, so if your particles are baked into the .blend, you may have to free the bake and save a copy of the file.

Comment: While your post certainly looks like snowfall and does look nice its sadly not what i am looking for, please see rhe 3dsmax tutorial - thats what i am trying to recreate in blender as i dont own max. thanks