# Particles started before animation does not appear in cycles animation render

Tags: animation, particles

I have been working on a little side project where I am trying to render with cycles an animation of snow falling.

The snow is a simple particle emitter from a plane, and the catch is that I want the snow to be already filling my camera view at the start of the animation. For that I set the "frame start" of the particle settings to -200 which seems to work after running the animation for multiple loops.

The problem is that when I render the animation (with cycles), the snow is present on the first frame but then start over from the second frame. Rendering juste the second frame shows the snow though...

Do you have any idea of what the problem is here and how I could fix it ?

Here is a simple .blend file showing the problem:

[image]

Thanks !

As a disclaimer, i have seen those two posts but they are pre-2.8 :

- [Procedural snow with particles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62889/procedural-snow-with-particles/62895#62895)
- [Start particles before animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67705/start-particles-before-animation)

Comment: Without looking at your file (sorry), but have you baked the particles?

Comment: I think i did not, I am relatively new to blender. Could you guide me to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So per Frederik's commment I looked into baking the particles and it seemed to do the trick...

In order to bake the particles, click "Bake All Dynamics" in the properties : 
[image]

Thanks !

Comment: This worked, but if you have multiple particle systems - make sure each particle system has a different name. If you don't do this only the first one you bake will show up.